# Average Velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

May any one explain to me this problem..

A particle moves a distance x_1=20m to the east (+ve direction) in a time t_1=10s. And again to the east a distance x_2=40m in time t_2=20s.

Find its average velocity..

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The average velocity, as you have stated is equal to displacement/ time. This is because average looks at the mean velocity of the object. During this time (30 seconds) the object has traveled 60 meters. You can draw a graph, or calculate the individual velocities of the separate components and notice that they have the same velocity, so the average will just be same. 
Cheers